# what is _interopRequireDefault ?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

I have seen an explanation on [this website](http://2ality.com) that say :

> _interopRequireDefault(): An ES6 CommonJS module is used as is (if it has a default export then it has a property named default). A normal
>   CommonJS module becomes the value of the property default. In other
>   words, in the later case, the module’s exports become the default
>   export.

In codes, there is often several `_interopRequireDefault` written in.

So if I understand well, since default export is a bunch of key/value on the whole file exported as a total entity, `_interopRequireDefault` allows to choose which modules will enter in the default export of a specific code that it ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To allow your code to consume modules written for Node.js as well as for ES6.

There is a differences between way modules work export in ES6 and CJS (Common JS specification).

**Modules in Common JS :**

```
module.exports = function () {};
```

**Modules in ES6 :**

```
export default function () {}
```

**_interopRequireDefault** has a rather simple logic :

```
function _interopRequireDefault(module) {
  const
      isCJSModule = module && module.__esModule,
      cjsStyedModule = { default: module };

  return isCJSModule ? module: cjsStyedModule;
}
```

CJS existed before ES6. Node.js still uses CJS version and all modules written originally for Node.js.

Although Node.js now supports ES6 modules experimentally, if you run with **--experimental** flag and name module files as `.mjs`.

Note : Now in 2020, Node.js also supports `.js` files with ES6 modules if you add a field `"type": "module"` in `package.json`. Read more here : https://medium.com/@nodejs/announcing-core-node-js-support-for-ecmascript-modules-c5d6dc29b663